# Error "value" does not exist - postgresql INSERT INTO issue

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

I've created a new table but I'm struggling to insert any data

The table looks like the below where the id column is an auto incrementing integer and name is a string column

```
select * from transaction_categories;
category_id | name 
------------+------
(0 rows)
```

and this is the query I'm trying to run:

```
INSERT INTO transaction_categories (category_id, name)
VALUES (1,’General’);
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR:  column "’general’" does not exist
LINE 2: VALUES (1,’General’);
```

Everything I've found so far on SO has pointed to using single quotes instead of double quotes, which I am. I have literally taken the basic insert statement from postgres documentation and copied and pasted the relevant table / column names, but I'm still running into this issue

What am I missing?!

Comment: Try simple quotes 'General'

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was a difference! or why the same key I've always used now types "non-simple" single quotes?

Comment: It's going to be because you have either weird keyboard or your operating system language is non standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this, traditional quotes and we do not need here to tell column names for insert query:

```
INSERT INTO transaction_categories 
VALUES (1,'General');
```